# What does Qt Creator `Separate debug info` means?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qmake

In Qt Creator, Tools, Options, Build & Run, Default Build Properties I can see

```
Separate debug info (Use Project Default/Enable/Disable)
```

What that means?

I was guessing it will put debug/release build on separate folders but that seems to happen anyway.

Comment: Qt has a very extensive web site with developer information. Perhaps you are not familiar with it. I wasn't very familiar with it too, until immediate;y after reading your question I ran a google search for "qt creator separate debug info", and the first link was to this developer site, which documented what that option for, and how to use it. For simple questions like this, it's often faster to simply use a Google search, instead of waiting until someone knowledgeable with the subject matter comes along and simply copy/pastes the same information.

Comment: Or maybe you read the documentation, tried it, and still had difficulty.  There are lots of target permutations and they may not all work quite as advertised (e.g. QtCreator/CMake/QNX on Arm).   Then you move on to developer commentary such as Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

**Separate debug info** in Qt is typically used when you compile in **Profile mode**.

Profile mode in Qt is used mainly for analyzing your application and profiling it. This mode creates an optimized binary file (as in Release Mode) with debug symbols in a different file (Debug mode, however, puts the symbols in the same file). This allows you to analyze the optimized application. So, this option in Qt tells the compiler to generate debug symbols in a separate file.

Don't worry. Sometimes Qt Documentation is a little dense and does not explain things in detail. You'll get used to it. Here are some useful links for understanding this:

1. How it works in gdb: https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Separate-Debug-Info.html
2. Specifying debug settings in Qt: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html
3. Using performance analyzer in Qt: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-cpu-usage-analyzer.html#using-the-performance-analyzer

Comment: Nevertheless, I'd like to emphasize that Qt has one of the best and most encompassing docs online which I have ever seen, which additionally is actively maintained. ;-)

Comment: I agree, it is usually very well documented and explained. I've learned Qt using that documentation, but little details like this are sometimes a little tricky to understand. I didn't mean anything against Qt, I really like it.

Comment: you say " with debug symbols in a different file". I was wondering where does the file exist? and what is the name and extension? Is it something like *.debug? I am not able to find the file.